# Pytoch, importing TorchVision on macOS Catalina problem

Tags: python, macos, torch, macos-catalina, torchvision

I installed the module torchvision on macOS Catalina, but if I try to run a python3 program with "import torchvision" inside it gives me an error.

```
pip list
Package     Version
----------- -------
numpy       1.17.2 
Pillow      6.2.0  
pip         19.3   
setuptools  40.8.0 
six         1.12.0 
torch       1.3.0  
torchvision 0.4.1  
wheel       0.33.1
```

Here I can see the module is installed but then if I run this:

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms, datsets
```

It says

```
$python3 1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import torchvision
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The most common problem is that `pip` and `python` point to different positions, respectively. You can first check it by `which pip` and `which python`. Let us know more information, so we could provide some concrete suggestions.

Comment: ~ gugliver$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
~ gugliver$ which python
/usr/bin/python

Here is the result